# Unicode escape error

Tags: python, unicode, syntax-error, unicode-escapes

experts!

I'm trying to make a twitter client, with Twython. For now, i retrieve the command from the interactive interpreter.

In a test to upload a picture, i passed this string:

```
   "tweet photo: 'tweeted from python test' + path: 'C:\Users\akhya_000\Pictures\My Pictures\Bing.png"
```

But i found it invalid and resulted in this error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 51-52: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Can someone help me, what's wrong with the string? What should i do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to escape the backslashes or use a raw string, since Python is seeing the `\U` and interpreting it as a [Unicode escape sequence](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code).

Escaping looks like this:

```
"tweet photo: 'tweeted from python test' + path: 'C:\\Users\\akhya_000\\Pictures\\My Pictures\\Bing.png"
```

A [raw string](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), where Python will ignore escape sequences, looks like this:

```
r"tweet photo: 'tweeted from python test' + path: 'C:\Users\akhya_000\Pictures\My Pictures\Bing.png"
```